# SystemD python task in Ubuntu 16

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, systemd

I am trying to execute a python3 with systemd in a ubuntu 16.
Following are the configs

```
[Unit]
Description=email notification server
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/email-noti
Restart=on-failure
ExecStart=/usr/lib/python3 /home/ubuntu/email-noti/email_reader.py 

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

*please note that `email_reader.py` import a config file and few python3 files from `/home/ubuntu/email-noti/`

but it always end with following error

```
● email-noti.service - email notification server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/email-noti.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2017-03-07 18:00:38 UTC; 6s ago
  Process: 11859 ExecStart=/usr/lib/python3 /home/ubuntu/email-noti/email_reader.py (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
 Main PID: 11859 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Mar 07 18:00:38 ip-172-31-24-115 systemd[1]: email-noti.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Mar 07 18:00:38 ip-172-31-24-115 systemd[1]: Stopped email notification server.
Mar 07 18:00:38 ip-172-31-24-115 systemd[1]: email-noti.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Mar 07 18:00:38 ip-172-31-24-115 systemd[1]: Failed to start email notification server.
```

but when i manually execute the `email_reader.py` works totally fine.

Any help appreciated

Comment: just curious, once we set WorkingDirectory it can import all .py files and .json files in the WorkingDirectory?

Comment: You are asking a variation of a systemd FAQ. [Difference between systemd and terminal starting program](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/339645/20239)